# MySQL calling stored function for unique id generator

Tags: mysql

I am new to the area of MySQL function but I can't seem to get this working properly.
Basically, every time I run a SELECT query from this one particular table, the next incremented value should be displayed.

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE testdb.id_generator(
  invoice_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (invoice_id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 16384
CHARACTER SET latin1
COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

Here is the function:

```
CREATE 
FUNCTION testdb.f_id_test()
  RETURNS INT(11)

BEGIN
  DECLARE v_val INT;
  DECLARE c_select CURSOR FOR SELECT invoice_id
                              FROM
                                id_generator;

  OPEN c_select;

  FETCH c_select INTO v_val;
  CLOSE c_select;

  UPDATE id_generator
SET
  invoice_id = invoice_id + 1;
  RETURN v_val;
END
```

Whenever I try to run the Query

```
  SELECT f_id_test()
  FROM
  id_generator
```

it says "Can't update table 'id_generator' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger." What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run your statement, try it without the "FROM id_generator", essentially just:

```
SELECT f_id_test()
```

Your function is already pulling the data from the id_generator table (so the FROM clause doesn't alter it), and the error is saying that your SELECT statement is using the same table that the function is trying to update.

Comment: That did it! That was simple enough.